# Expand symlinked directory in finder

Tags: finder, macos, folders, textmate, symlink

Is there a way to make it so that in list view in Finder a symbolically linked directory can be expanded like a regular directory? I would just switch to column view, but I'm using TextMate 2's file browser, which appears to use Finder's list view.

I have no issue with getting my hands dirty with the console or editing plists if need be - I used Linux for years and fiddled with a Hackintosh for a while before switching to Mac. I'll also understand if The Mighty Apple Hath Spoken. I've just found [very little](http://earthwithsun.com/questions/351156/os-x-prevent-finder-file-chooser-from-following-directory-symlinks) on the topic. (And in my case it's on Macintosh HD so unmounting and remounting is not an option.)

Comment: See this related question: http://superuser.com/questions/351156/os-x-prevent-finder-file-chooser-from-following-directory-symlinks

Answer (score 2):

One solution, as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80875/what-is-the-unix-command-to-create-a-hardlink-to-a-directory-in-os-x), would be to use a hardlink for the directory. It's very important that you understand the implications listed in [Bob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80875/what-is-the-unix-command-to-create-a-hardlink-to-a-directory-in-os-x#answer-4707231) as well as only use the *hunlink* utility (also in Bob's answer) to remove any directories created via the *hlink* utility.

I certainly would not recommend this solution for anyone who isn't comfortable understanding the details laid out in Bob's answer and/or for a shared system where not **every** user is aware of which directories are hard links **and** how to properly handle them.

Comment: This is useful information, but it doesn't directly answer the question -- one would hope to find a way to configure the Finder to automatically expand symlinks to directories.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, there is not a way to get the nice little triangle to easily expand a symlink directory in the Finder's list view.

According to ["Folder Aliases in Dock or List View cannot be expanded?" on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/34385/folder-aliases-in-dock-or-list-view-cannot-be-expanded), "This is a known bug and is even mentioned in [John Siracusa's review on Snow Leopard](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2009/08/mac-os-x-10-6/17/)."

This is consistent with this [Textmate Thread](http://textmate.1073791.n5.nabble.com/Symlinks-as-Expandable-Directories-td26165.html) which discusses the issue without finding a solution.